# Animated series where the main antagonist is the "East Wind"/"Blizzard"

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I am trying to find a series which I cought only a few episodes of as a kid, but which seemed really interesting. To be fair, it might also have been an animated movie broken down into parts, though I find that less likely.

- I watched the series in the late 90's - but, as I grew up in Romania, it is likely that this is in fact an older series.
- The protagonists (afaict) were a young girl and a boy (possibly of a different age).
- The episode(s) I watched were playing in a harbour town, and the characters wanted to catch a ship.
- There was repeated queer talk about the [Crivăț](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criv%C4%83%C8%9B) (as it was called in the Romanian dubbing - this is a specific Romanian meteorological phenomenon, which might have been used as a stand-in for "blizzard" or [East Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_wind)) which made me fairly sure it would shape out to be the story's primary antagonist.
- The series was drawn in a nice, but classic way, Walt-Disney-ish as far as I can assign the style.
- The general atmosphere of the series was gloomy, and many of the colours were bleak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for this (*Legend of the North Wind*)

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you SO much!!